# Wearable electronics in which kind of electrically-insulated mold?

Tags: prototyping, wearable, printed

I have a wearable electronics that I need to keep in my finger. I don't have the resources to put a prototype into something small like custom ASIC so I would like to find a way to put it to shape it needs (this may result into short-circuit so and other problems so have to consider different ways). The battery inside the mold last months so it is not necessary to have a charging point. I have considered the following ways to create the mold:

> - prototyping
>
>   1. urethane
>   2. using electrical-tape
>   3. 3D-printed mold
>   4. silicone
> - more expensive
>
>   5. printed electronics
>   6. injection mold

[image]

*Are there some common methods to have electronics in molds or containers for wearable electronics not to cause problems such as short-circuits?*